# Access for Statistical Analysis using the Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, api, statistics

We are small company in Malaysia and intended to do a small research to analyze technology trends. We would like to use the Stack Exchange API for this purpose but we are afraid it might get detected as offensive by your back end server.

Is there a way we can avoid this outcome? Or any other suggestion to assist us to achieve our goals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For analyzing large chunks of data, don't use the API. Use [the *Stack Exchange Data Explorer* (SEDE)](http://data.stackexchange.com/help), that's what it's there for.  SEDE data lags real-time by 1 to 5 weeks, but that's no big problem for most statistical purposes.

For intense "Big data" analysis beyond even SEDE's capabilities, use [the quarterly data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). (Thanks, Tim Stone, for the reminder.)

---

If you really must use the API, follow these guidelines:

1. [Register your app](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register).
2. Make sure you do not bust your [quotas](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).
3. Monitor and respect [the `backoff` flag](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper).
4. For anything more, contact the API team and negotiate for special access.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know SEDE exist. It seems like SQL interface which I could try!

Comment: @ChrisLiaw The quarterly [data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) are also an option if you need to work with the data in a more intensive way than Data Explorer supports.

Comment: @TimStone, the data dumps includes all previous data? I mean if I grab some GBs of dump from the site, those including all previous data up to dump date?

Comment: @ChrisLiaw Yes, that's correct (excluding deleted data, of course)

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That's very useful for offline analysis!